# Errors using the apkTool

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

I have used this site to help me with the apkTool in the past, however I have today come up against an error I can't quite get my head around.

I am DE-compiling an APK which was written by a predecessor as it requires a few tweaks and he hasn't left any source files behind..

So, As far as I'm aware I have the latest tool available, using windows 7 64bit.

I have added the framework from my test tablet which the app runs fine on. And this is what I get..

This is the error screen

http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/4291/63yc.png

Anyone have an idea at what the issue is here? Any help really appreciated.

Comment: have you copied apktool.jar in c:\\windows location of your computer.??

Comment: nope..... I havent done it before..

Comment: then please copy that jar file. your error will be gone.

Comment: Ok, I generally decode the APK to the apktool folder, which has the apktool.jar there already. So will it make a difference?

Comment: yes, as per my knowledge, either you need to run command from c:\\windows by putting your apkttool directory there or you can simply copy apktool.jar in that location, check  first.

Comment: Ill give it a go and let you know if It works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an open issue on a similar exception (scroll to the bottom):
https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/issues/detail?id=477

Comment: Yes I see. Ive had no luck moving the apktool.jar to C:\\windows

Comment: It does partially decompile, but I lose a lot, and it doesn't create the .yml file, so recompiling is impossible... The only thing I can see which is the same as the other person is that were both using windows 7 64bit.

Comment: Are there any other ways to decompile an APK apart from this tool?